# How to compressed CSS correctly

Tags: html, css

I used online CSS compressed tools for compress my css. this css is animation.css it has several animation scripts. like

```
.animate1
   {
        -webkit-animation-delay: .5s;
        -moz-animation-delay: .5s;
        -ms-animation-delay: .5s;
        animation-delay: .5s;
    }

    .animate2{
        -webkit-animation-delay: 1.0s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 1.0s;
        -ms-animation-delay: 1.0s;
        animation-delay: 1.0s;
    }
```

I used several online tool such as

https://cssminifier.com/

https://csscompressor.net/

http://www.cleancss.com/css-minify/

but my problem is after compress the css it show error on code also animations are stop working. what is the best way to do that. or any one can suggest a correct tool. here this is my css code look like after compressed,

[image]

Comment: What's the error…?

Comment: I dont see a problem with what you did

Comment: this is a better question than before. I am not sure why it is being closed unless it is because your examples do not give any problems

Answer (score 2):

```
.animate1{-webkit-animation-delay:.5s;-moz-animation-delay:.5s;-ms-animation-delay:.5s;animation-delay:.5s}
.animate2{-webkit-animation-delay:1s;-moz-animation-delay:1s;-ms-animation-delay:1s;animation-delay:1s}
```

I use https://csscompressor.net/ but in advanced settings I disable optimize shorthands for older browsers

Comment: yes I changed some advanced settings.. it was removing some {} and semicolons.. thanx

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to remove semicolons and {} then you can use below below reference source code, because I was not able to find it's live link but I found CSS compression tool source code.

If you know how to make such tool then you can do customization as per your need. For your reference you can use advanced [CSS Compression Tool](https://www.technicalarp.com/2022/01/css-minifier-tool-css-compressor-tool.html) Source code, it has more options that can be very helpful for someone looking with more options.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31453855)